# highcharts putting ajax/json data at 1970

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, highcharts

I am attempting to have an ajax request return a datetime array and then put that data in highcharts. I have the data being returning like this as a json array:

```
[[1395489600000,29.010971409934],[1395493200000,29.234899961948],[1395496800000,29.712949994206],[1395500400000,29.975449994206],[1395504000000,29.656849956512],[1395507600000,28.24099997282],[1395511200000,27.234581782601],[1395514800000,26.778649961948],[1395518400000,25.775299978256],[1395522000000,25.269349956512],[1395525600000,24.856550049782],[1395529200000,24.219200181961],[1395532800000,24.15609107451],[1395536400000,24.519350206852],[1395540000000,25.194349956512],[1395543600000,25.062799978256],[1395547200000,24.950599956512],[1395550800000,24.575600242615],[1395554400000,23.994500303268],[1395558000000,24.452763795853],[1395561600000,26.619349956512],[1395565200000,29.037949976325],[1395568800000,33.930950012803],[1395572400000,40.999399828911],[1395576000000,45.387049818039]]
```

The chart will render, but the data above does not show up, and the chart navigator goes all the way back to 1970 and shows one point at on Jan 1, 12am at a value of 0.0. I am pretty stumped to say the least. Code below

php:

```
$ret = array();
//SQL query here
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
extract($row);
$datatime1 = strtotime($datatime)*1000;
$ret[] = array($datatime1, $value*1.0);
}
mysql_close($db);
echo json_encode($ret);
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/php/TempHist3.php',
    method: 'GET', // or GET
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
   var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
   $("#hiddendiv").html(data);
   chart.series[0].setData(data);
 },
    error: function(data){
        $("#hiddendiv").html("yousuck");
    }
    });
```

Comment: can you make a http://jsfiddle.net demo if this?

Comment: Trying to, but having trouble getting ajax to call my php in jsfiddle. Does it look like I am missing anything to format the data correctly?

Comment: was able to make a local demo of it: http://windypi.org/forecast4.php

Comment: you can see the data returned by ajax above the chart, and notice the navigator's extreme range

Comment: I can see error in console: `http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12` - could you fix that? Also, right now data looks fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this worked, and from the sound of it I did something evil but...

changing this:

```
      chart.series[0].setData(data);
```

to this:

```
      chart.series[0].setData(eval( '(' + data + ')' ));
```

Worked!

Ideally there would be a way not to use eval, but this method I have posted here seems to be the easiest way of getting datetime info into highcharts by simply sending the time as a unix*1000 timestamp, rather than trying to parse into a Date.UTC() function on the client side.